# c++ new inplace under win32 API (visual studio 2010 express)

Tags: c++, winapi, new-operator, operator-keyword

I am trying to do new inplace under visual studio 2010 express.

It does not work:

```
VirtualLink* vLink = new( mVirtualLinks[0].mVirtualLink ) VirtualLink;

1>d:\workspace\cms\ng\windows\applications\temp\c2acommunication\c2acommunication\networkmanagerdb.cpp(362): error C2660: 'operator new' : function does not take 2 arguments
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..... Spent too much time on this one

Answer (score 4):

You need to `#include <new>` to use placement new.